# How to use device tree to get a rotary-encoder device (NXP Yocto)

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-tree, nxp-microcontroller

**What I want to do:**

Create a rotary encoder device in Linux with Yocto Project and device tree (/dev/input/rotary-encoder). The device should be visible after boot, so that it can be used in user space.

**My Hardware:**

i.MX8M Mini Evaluation Board (imx8mm evk)

Rotary encoder using two GPIOs

EXP_GPIO13, EXP_GPIO14: [Expansion Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hThzK.png)

**My Software:**

Yocto from NXP building minimal image for i.MX8M Mini Evaluation Board.

Image:

```
inherit core-image

IMAGE_FEATURES += "debug-tweaks"

IMAGE_INSTALL = "\
    packagegroup-core-boot \
    kernel-modules \
    console-tools \
    kbd-keymaps \
    gcc \
    packagegroup-core-buildessential \
    nano \
    ntp \
    "
```

Distro based on:

```
require conf/distro/poky.conf
```

**What I tried:**

I changed the dts file and added code for the rotary encoder (arch/arm64/boot/dts/freescale/fsl-imx8mm-evk.dts):

```
/ {
    ...

    rotary@0 {
        compatible = "rotary-encoder";
        gpios = <&pca6416 14 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>, <&pca6416 13 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        linux,axis = <REL_WHEEL>;
        rotary-encoder,relative-axis;
        rotary-encoder,half-period;
        status = "okay";
    };
};
```

What is the right way and do I maybe need some device driver in addition to the device tree file? I thought Linux would have one for rotary encoders. The problem is that my knowledge about device trees is limited. I tried to find a solution via google, but couldn't. Maybe someone can help how to integrate this with the evaluation board.

I also found that link: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/devices/rotary-encoder.rst and interpreted the text in a way that i don't need a driver/module:

> Because the driver uses generic device properties, this can be done either via device tree, ACPI, or using static board files, like in example below:

I also opened a thread in NXP Community: https://community.nxp.com/thread/525581

Comment: You should ignore the bit about static board files. In addition to adding the rotary encoder device to the device tree, you also need to configure the kernel to build the rotary_encoder driver, either built-in or as a loadable kernel module. The config option is CONFIG_INPUT_GPIO_ROTARY_ENCODER which depends on CONFIG_INPUT_MISC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both configuration options are enabled [=y], but it is still not working. I guess I maybe have a different configuration issue, but can't figure out what.